# Obtener una posición aleatoria de un array sin que este se repita en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, algoritmos, random

Quiero que cuando apriete el boton se coloree uno de los elementos p, y cuando lo vuelva a apretar no quiero que este se coloree de nuevo mas bien quiero que se pinte otro

en mi código hay un bucle que que genera 10 elementos p y cada uno tiene su numero

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
const paraContent = document.getElementById("para-content")

let arrayContainer = [];
let existe = false


for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    let paragraph = document.createElement("p")
    paragraph.textContent = i
    paraContent.appendChild(paragraph)
}

let arrayContentPara = document.querySelectorAll("p")

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let aleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)
    console.log(aleatorio)
    recorrerArray(aleatorio)
})

const recorrerArray = azar =>   {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayContentPara.length; i++) {
        const element = arrayContentPara[i].innerText;
        const recorridoAleatorio = arrayContentPara[azar].innerText

        if (element === recorridoAleatorio) {
            arrayContentPara[azar].style.color ="red"
            arrayContentPara[azar].style.fontSize ="2rem"
            arrayContainer.push(arrayContentPara[azar].innerText)
            break;
        }
    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción muy similar a la de @WinterOwl es la de guardar los indices de los "p" origianes en un array, e ir eliminandolas de ese array, no del de párrafos, esto podría servir si queremos hacer otras interacciones distintas e independientes con los mismos parrafos, `[...document.querySelectorAll("p")]` permanecería siempre igual:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn")
const paraContent = document.getElementById("para-content")


for (let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
  let paragraph = document.createElement("p")
  paragraph.textContent = i
  paraContent.appendChild(paragraph)
}

let arrayContentPara = [...document.querySelectorAll("p")]

let indicesP = arrayContentPara.map((e, i) => i);// <-- Los índices de los "p" como valores

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  if (!indicesP.length) {
    indicesP = arrayContentPara.map((e, i) => {
      e.style.color = "black";
      e.style.fontSize = "1rem";
      return i;
    });
  }

  let aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * indicesP.length);

  recorrerArray(aleatorio);

})

const recorrerArray = (azar) => {

  arrayContentPara[indicesP[azar]].style.color = "red";
  arrayContentPara[indicesP[azar]].style.fontSize = "2rem";
  indicesP.splice(azar, 1);

}
```

```html
<button id="btn">
  boton
</button>
<div id="para-content">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basado en lo que describes en tu pregunta me parece que no es necesario **"crear un numero aleatorio sin repetir"**, si no mas bien **evitar que el mismo párrafo se trate de pintar de nuevo**.

***Archivo JS:***

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const cln = document.getElementById("clean");
const paraContent = document.getElementById("para-content");
let arrayContentPara = [];

const start = () => {
    paraContent.innerHTML = '';
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        let paragraph = document.createElement("p")
        paragraph.textContent = i
        paraContent.appendChild(paragraph)
    }
    
    arrayContentPara = [...document.querySelectorAll("p")];
}

cln.addEventListener("click", event => start());

btn.addEventListener("click", event => {
    let aleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random()*arrayContentPara.length))
    arrayContentPara.length && modifyParagraph(aleatorio)
})

const modifyParagraph = azar =>   {
    arrayContentPara[azar].style.color ="red";
    arrayContentPara[azar].style.fontSize ="2rem";
    arrayContentPara.splice(azar,1);
}

//------------START THE PROGRAM
start();
```

***Archivo HTML:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="para-content"></div>
        <button id="btn">Color</button>
        <button id="clean">Clean</button>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

La explicación es así, al obtener todos los párrafos con **querySelectorAll** use el operador **spread** para pasarlo de una **NodeList** a un array común, esto con el fin de usar el método **splice** que las **NodeList** no poseen.
Después cada que se le haga click al botón color se generara el numero aleatorio **entre 0 y la longitud del array menos 1** con el método **Math.random**, se llama el metodo **modifyParagraph** y se pinta el elemento correspondiente al arreglo basado en el numero aleatorio.
Por ultimo con el método **splice** saco ese elemento del arreglo y la próxima vez genere un numero aleatorio será con la nueva longitud del array y se pintara un párrafo distinto.
Agregue también un botón clean por si necesitas reiniciar el programa.

Comment: si muchas gracias bro